# Cannot configure System.Net in .NET Framework 4.7.2

Tags: .net, .net-framework-version, .net-4.8

We had below System.Net configuration in our app.config for maxconnections. This was working fine when we were using .NET Framework version 4.6.2.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <!--AuthenticationConfiguration is reading off of app.config. Once it's updated, remove these lines-->
    <add key="validIssuers" value="https://sts.windows.net/xxxxx/" />
    <add key="tenant" value="microsoft.onmicrosoft.com" />
    <add key="validAudiences" value="xxxx,xxxxx" />
    <add key="enableValidateAudience" value="true" />
    <add key="aadInstance" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}" />

    <!-- CORS Settings-->
    <add key="corsAllowedDomains" value="*" />
    <add key="corsAllowedHeaders" value="*" />
    <add key="corsAllowedVerbs" value="*" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.net>
    <connectionManagement>
      <add address = "*" maxconnection = "100" />
    </connectionManagement>
  </system.net>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6" />
  </startup>
  <runtime>
    <gcServer enabled="true" />
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

After we upgraded to .NET Framework 4.7.2, we started getting the following exceptions:

System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration system failed to initialize ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized configuration section system.net.

How do we configure the maxconnection value under .NET Framework 4.7.2

Comment: There's no difference between 4.6 and 4.7. The error means there's a problem in the config file. Please post a *full* config file that reproduces the error. If you google for that error message you'll find it appears in *.NET Core* if you try to read a legacy config file using the `ConfigurationManager` compatibility class

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  Please see my config file as edited